# Vert.x modify content of static file

Tags: vert.x

I have a Vert.x HTTP server with static files, that are handled with

```
router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create())
```

This is working fine. My question is - is it possible to modify one of my static file? For example - in `index.html` i have a meta tag

```
<meta name="my-token" content="${MY-TOKEN}">
```

and i want to replace `${MY-TOKEN}` part with my generated data. Is Vert.x have some possibilities to modify it or it's not possible and i need to use one of the template engines?

Comment: Sounds like you want to modify the file‘s contents before sending it out as response. That’s what template engines are for!